# How do I change the data displayed, not the data itself, with QSqlTableModel?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I'm using QTableView with QSqlTableModel to display data in a table. I'm displaying integer values as other unicode values- for example, displaying 0 as a checkmark.

```
self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
index = self.model.index(0,5)
qv = QVariant(u"\u2713")
self.model.setData(index, qv)
```

This effectively changes the display, but it also changes the actual data. Is there a way in QTableView or QSqlTableModel to change the display or not the data? Or should I use a workaround, like saving the original data in a file and writing it back when the program closes?

Thanks!
--Erin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the [edit strategy](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqltablemodel.html#EditStrategy-enum) so that changes are not submitted immediately:

```
self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
```